# Uninstall Ubuntu with no boot problem afterward

Tags: installation, boot, uninstall

I'm trying to install Ubuntu on my laptop (ProBook 4331s) that comes with preinstalled win7, so I have no recovery CD or something, but somehow it has recovery HD, separated from HD C & D.

So far, the only way I knew to uninstall Ubuntu was, by deleting the Ubuntu's partition, from win7.
But it's damaging the boot loader.
Once I read about installing "easybcd 2.2" and make use of it before deleting the Ubuntu partition. Then I checked here and there, even there's some problem arose from using "easybcd 2.2".

So I'm asking opinion, using "easybcd 2.2" is the right way in avoid booting messed up when uninstalling Ubuntu by deleting its partition, even without recovery CD?

Comment: PS if you use easyBCD then you don't have to do anything other than remove the Ubuntu partition. But you should always have a Windows repair CD handy.

Answer (score 0):

I have a laptop with preloaded Vista, and having a "recovery" partition just like yours. I have installed/uninstalled the last few versions of Ubuntu several times without any problem using "Wubi".

I have some 2 tips for u.

1. You can create the recovery DVDs by yourself, just find the "**system repair disc**" wizard in **backup and restore** dialog box. Those 3/4 dvds will prove to be a great time and money saver in case of emergency. Get it done ASAP! 
   Here is a link that might help you http://windows.microsoft.com/en-IN/windows7/Create-a-system-repair-disc
2. You can create logical partitions from Win7 itself then use Wubi to install Ubuntu on that partition. I think you already know this one.

Answer (score 0):

I have no expirience with EasyBCD at all, so I can't help you with that. But there are multiple ways to achieve the same goal.

But there are 2 things you can do here:

**Option 1:**

Either use a windows system repair cd/dvd, which you can make in windows:

> **Making a repair cd/dvd**
>
> Open **Backup and Restore** by clicking the **Start button**, clicking
>   **Control Panel**, clicking **System and Maintenance**, and then clicking **Backup and Restore**.
>
> In the left pane, click **Create a system repair disc**, and then
>   follow the steps. If you're prompted for an administrator password or
>   confirmation, type the password or provide confirmation.
>
> **To use the system repair disc**
>
> Insert the system repair disc into your CD or DVD drive.
>
> Restart your computer using the computer's power button.
>
> When booting press F12, to select boot devices and select cd/dvd drive.
>
> If prompted, press any key to start the computer from the system
>   repair disc.
>
> Choose your language settings, and then click Next.
>
> Select a recovery option, and then click Next.
>
> And now the disk will check what to do

**Option 2:**

Or you could always download and use [Resc-a-tux](http://www.supergrubdisk.org/rescatux/).

This is a live cd with a primary goal: Restoring grub/installing grub. It's a nice program which I used after windows just removed my grub without asking, and it worked like a charm.

You can also use it to boot just windows, or any OS.
So just removed the Ubuntu partition, and then run this live cd, it will fix your boatloader, and you are done in 5 mintes or less.

**How to use resc-a-tux**: Boot the disk(explained in step 1) and when it is booted, a windows will popup with the option:"Restore GRUB" or something similar.

```
**Rescatux features:**

Fixes GRUB and GRUB2

Regenerates Debian/Ubuntu grub menues

Check and fix filesystems

Fixes Windows MBR

Blank Windows passwords

Boot Info Script

Change Gnu/Linux password

Regenerate sudoers file

**Extra tools:**

Synaptic

Gparted 0.7
```